# Pointer to an array of function pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
int (*rdPtrList[4])(unsigned int addr, unsigned int data);
```

The above declares an array of size 4 of pointers for functions that returns an int and takes two unsigned int. I would like to make a pointer to this array. Is this possible in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, tricky tricky!!!

I *think* this works

```
int (*(*rdPtrList)[4])(unsigned int addr, unsigned int data);
```

because the compiler tells me `_countof(*rdPtrList)` is 4.

---

(I wish you could just say `int function(unsigned int addr, unsigned int data)[4]*` like you can in D, it's so much more readable: it would be a "function array pointer".)

Comment: This compiled, I will have to get back to you as to whether it worked!

Comment: @jliu83: Haha okay! (It probably did. :P)

Comment: The right way to verify that you declared the pointer correctly is to assign the address of the array to it, i.e. `ptr_to_fixed_length_function_array = &array_of_functions;`. If the type isn't correct, your compiler should complain about this assignment.

Answer (score 21):

Leaving out the parameters to keep the following easier to read:

```
        p         -- p
       *p         -- is a pointer
      (*p)[4]     -- to a 4-element array
     *(*p)[4]     -- of pointers
    (*(*p)[4])()  -- to functions 
int (*(*p)[4])(); -- returning int.
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
typedef int(*rdPtrList_t[4])(unsigned int addr, unsigned int data);
rdPtrList_t *ptrToArray;
```

Comment: This worked!  What would be the syntax for not using typedef?  Is it even possible without the typedef?

Comment: @Idanko:  Both solutions worked.  However I prefer the not to use the typedef.  Thanks.